# print Section name and it's own employees with their ages using jagged arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, iteration, jagged-arrays

I am trying to use jagged arrays in order to print sections' names with their names of employees and ages
I tried like this:

```
string[] sections= new string[50];
            sections[0] = "It";
            sections[1] = "Hr";
            string[][,] employeeTree = new string[6][,];
            
            employeeTree [0] = new string[,] { {"mark","20"},{ "mike", "30" },{ "michel", "3" },{ "joerge", "40" }};
```

**My problem is iterating the employees arrays to print them**  ,
how can I do it? and if there were examples it will be more better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 2-D Array structure for employeeTree.
So the straightforward way would be to iterate twice on the 2-D array to access the elements.

The simplest way is like below :

```
foreach(var emp in employeeTree.Where(x => x != null) )
                foreach(var object1 in emp)
                    Console.WriteLine(object1.ToString());
```

This will print the below output:

mark

20

mike

30

michel

3

joerge

40

You can do formatting on this to print them in a single line like below :

```
foreach (var emp in employeeTree.Where(x => x != null))
                for (int i = 0; i < emp.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(emp[i,0] + emp[i,1]);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        foreach(string[,] employee in employeeTree.Where(x => x != null)) {
            int max = employee.GetLength(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine($"{employee[i, 0]}, {employee[i, 1]}");
            }
        }
```